# Ubuntu 12.04 VNC Server with Java Client

Tags: 12.04, vnc, remote-access, remote, remote-control

I'm trying to setup a machine that I can admin remotely using VNC and I'm a tad stuck

The particulars:

- These machines are inaccessible after they've been setup and as I
  need to set up a lot of them, I'd like to be able to do as much (if
  not all) of the setup through SSH
- I need to be able to connect to them via a java-based client. I've managed to get this to work using this guide (http://hartlessbydesign.com/blog/view/195-how-to-set-up-a-vnc-web-java-client-for-ubuntu.html) but I have to use the built-in VNC server package which is awful and I don't know how to configure it for better performance
- I need to be able to interact with the default session (is that the correct term?) over VNC, i.e. I need to be able to control the session you would see if you were sat in front of the machine, not an alternative session

Does anyone know how to either improve the performance of the built-in package or install and configure an alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

VNC is known to be slow. May I suggest using [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx)? With it you can set up unattended access by creating a static password. You can control the computers from Ubuntu, Debian, RedHat, CentOS, Fedora, SUSE, Mac, Windows, and mobile devices! Be sure to have TeamViewer run on startup.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but we really need a web-browser compatible thing - something where we can have a list of links which takes us to a page that has a vnc session open on that particular machine